# phpunit testdox friendly output with data providers

Tags: phpunit

When I run `phpunit --testdox` with @dataProvider I get output like this:

```
MyTestClass
✔ My function data set ""
✔ My function data set ""
✔ My function data set ""
```

Is there a way of getting `testdox` to display a friendly description for each data set? Something like:

```
MyTestClass
✔ My function data set "one"
✔ My function data set "two"
✔ My function data set "three"
```

Example code:

```
class MyTestClassTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider dataSets
     */
    public function testMyFunction(string $data)
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

    public function dataSets()
    {
        return [
            ['one'],
            ['two'],
            ['three'],
        ];
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I'm using phpunit version 7.3.2

Comment: Which version of PHPUnit do you use? A lot work has been done to improve TestDox output in recent versions.

Comment: @SebastianBergmann phpunit version 7.3.2 (should have put it in the question)

Comment: Why are you stuck on PHPUnit 7.3? Please update to the latest PHPUnit 7.5 release. It's backward compatible with PHPUnit 7.3 and should already be better. Do yourself a favor, though, and update to the latest PHPUnit 8. It has much better TestDox capabilities, especially with regards to data providers.

Comment: @SebastianBergmann No reason just haven't run `composer update` for a while! I will definitely check out version 8. Looks like I need to make a few changes to my test code though.

Comment: @SebastianBergmann version 8 is better in that it shows `set #1` etc instead of just `""`. Would be nice if there was an option to display the dataset values like how the `--debug` flag does it.

Comment: You want to use the `@testdox` annotation and use placeholder to get custom text that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Add index to your date sets

```php
class MyTestClassTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider dataSets
     */
    public function testMyFunction(string $data)
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

    public function dataSets()
    {
        return [
            'one' => ['one'],
            'two' => ['two'],
            'three' => ['three'],
        ];
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
My Test Class
 ✔ My function with one
 ✔ My function with two
 ✔ My function with three
```

Or, you may add `@testdox` to your docblock

```php
class MyTestClassTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider dataSets
     * @testdox My custom testdox output with $data
     */
    public function testMyFunction(string $data)
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

    public function dataSets()
    {
        return [
            ['one'],
            ['two'],
            ['three'],
        ];
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
My Test Class
 ✔ My custom testdox output with one
 ✔ My custom testdox output with two
 ✔ My custom testdox output with three
```

Comment: I would update your answer to add more context on where and why this change needs to be applied.